# How can I disable auto-detect and use a Macbook Pro USB port as a power source only?

Tags: usb, macbook-pro

I have a Navigon navigation device which goes into PC mode each time it is connected to my laptop. In this PC mode, the device is unusable and just shows an icon of a device connected to a PC.

My question is, how do I prevent the Macbook Pro from communicating with the device so that the device sees the USB port as only a power source and not a computer.

Answer (score 2):

You can build a custom "hacked" cable with data (two central) wires disconnected and ground and +5V wires intact.

Easiest way to do this is to open (using scalpel or knife for example) the usual USB extender cable and cut that two wires. When needed it can be repaired to function as usual USB extender again.

Note that it is not USB compliant and may cause problems if too many devices are using power from USB.